# sorting vector object of Student based on last first id

Tags: c++, c++11

this is the string to compare, lastname+firstName and id
comp is public, my sort method does not work, I am not able to find where the code fails, I am supposed to have the students listed in the order

```
comp=new char[strlen(lName)+strlen(fName)+strlen(id)+1];
```

this is my student constructor:

```
Student::Student(char * first, char * last, char *i,char * stand, int credit, double g, Date * d, Date * matricDate){
        lName=last;
        fName=first;
        id=i;
        standing=stand;
        credits=credit;
        gpa=g;
        dob=d;
        matDate=matricDate;
        comp=new char[strlen(lName)+strlen(fName)+strlen(id)+1];
        sprintf(comp,"%s%s%s",lName,fName,id);
};
```

this is the operator I overload

```
 bool Student::operator<(const Student &second){
                if(comp<second.comp){
                        return true;
                }else{
                        return false;
                }
        };
```

I have the student list as:

```
 vector<Student *> roster_list;
```

I add student like this:

```
void Roster::addStudent(Student *student){

        roster_list.push_back(student); 

        };
```

here is my sort:

```
void Roster::mySort(){
        sort(roster_list.begin(),roster_list.end());
};
```

my main:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Roster.cpp"
#include "Date.cpp"
#include "Student.cpp"

using namespace std;


int main(){

        Roster *r=new Roster();
        Date *d=new Date(12,05,1987);
        Student *st=new Student("Jason", "Sam", "124542", "sophomore", 34, 4.0, d,d);
        Student *st2=new Student("Ahmad", "Khan", "23452", "freshman", 34, 4.0, d,d);

        Student *st3=new Student("Selam", "Can", "23431", "freshman", 34, 3.0, d,d);
        Student *st4=new Student("Andrew", "Rosenberg", "34523", "Senior", 34, 4.0, d,d);
        Student *st5=new Student("Selam", "Can", "23431", "freshman", 34, 3.0, d,d);


        r->addStudent(st);
        r->addStudent(st2);
        r->addStudent(st3);
        r->addStudent(st4);

        // Student 3 and 5 are same 
        // == operator check
        if(*st3==*st5){
                cout<<"Students are same \n";
        }

        // != overloading operator check
        if(*st3!=*st4){
                cout<<"Students are different\n";
        }

        cout<<"################Before Sorting###############\n";
        r->toString();
        cout<<"################After Sorting###############\n";
        r->mySort();
        r->toString();



        cout<<"\n"<<st->getComp();
        cout<<"\n"<<st3->getComp();

        return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Students are same 
Students are different
################Before Sorting###############
Student Info:Jason      Sam     124542  sophomore       4
Birth Date: December 5, 1987
Matric Date: December 5, 1987
Student Info:Ahmad      Khan    23452   freshman        4
Birth Date: December 5, 1987
Matric Date: December 5, 1987
Student Info:Selam      Can     23431   freshman        3
Birth Date: December 5, 1987
Matric Date: December 5, 1987
Student Info:Andrew     Rosenberg       34523   Senior  4
Birth Date: December 5, 1987
Matric Date: December 5, 1987
################After Sorting###############
Student Info:Jason      Sam     124542  sophomore       4
Birth Date: December 5, 1987
Matric Date: December 5, 1987
Student Info:Ahmad      Khan    23452   freshman        4
Birth Date: December 5, 1987
Matric Date: December 5, 1987
Student Info:Selam      Can     23431   freshman        3
Birth Date: December 5, 1987
Matric Date: December 5, 1987
Student Info:Andrew     Rosenberg       34523   Senior  4
Birth Date: December 5, 1987
Matric Date: December 5, 1987

SamJason124542
CanSelam23431
```

I tried this

```
bool StudentSort(Student* lhs, Student* rhs) {
    return (*lhs)<(*rhs);
}



void Roster::mySort(){
        sort(roster_list.begin(),roster_list.end(),StudentSort);
};
```

still does not work, I get compilation error I have gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC)

this is the error I get after this try:

```
Roster.cpp: In member function ‘void Roster::mySort()’:
Roster.cpp:69: error: argument of type ‘bool (Roster::)(Student*, Student*)’ does not match ‘bool (Roster::*)(Student*, Student*)’
```

Comment: The problem is you are storing pointers, so your less-than operator is never used in the sort. A simple pointer comparison is used instead. The best solution would be not to store pointers. There seems to be no reason for doing so.

Comment: To that we can add the the sort criterion is bugged, appending the different sort keys does not work in all cases, you must compare each key individually.

Comment: You haven't given us a definition of the Student type, so its a little hard to comment on how to write functions that operate on it.

Comment: I added an error after your response

Answer (score 2):

Your vector/list contains only `Student*` , not `Student`'s.
So, you would need to provide Std::sort something that compares `Student*` correctly.
As it stands, default sort will probably being sorting by memory location, not the semantic value of the pointed to object.

```
// assumes operator< above,which it doesnt.
bool StudentSortFn(Student* lhs, Student* rhs) {
    return (*lhs)<(*rhs);
}
```

Of course, it turns out the original `operator<` has much the same issue embedded in it. Its comparing `char*` fields based on pointer values (memory addresses), not on semantic contents.
It need to be rewritten to use strcmp or something similar like:

```
 bool Student::operator<(const Student &second){
        return strcmp(comp,second.comp)<0;
    };
```

Comment: when I call void Roster::mySort(){
        sort(roster_list.begin(),roster_list.end(),StudentSortFn);
};  I sill get error

Comment: @user103421 Unless you say what the error is no-one will be able to help you.

Comment: ok, user103421 I have edited my answer a little, should be closer now :)

Comment: somehow I am not able to use StudentSort method I am not able to call it within sort method, can you check my error I posted ?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to sort Students when your vector is a vector of pointers. Simple way is to rewrite without pointers

```
vector<Student> roster_list;

void Roster::addStudent(Student student){

    roster_list.push_back(student); 

    };

int main(){

    Roster r;
    Date d(12,05,1987);
    Student st("Jason", "Sam", "124542", "sophomore", 34, 4.0, d,d);
    Student st2("Ahmad", "Khan", "23452", "freshman", 34, 4.0, d,d);

    Student st3("Selam", "Can", "23431", "freshman", 34, 3.0, d,d);
    Student st4("Andrew", "Rosenberg", "34523", "Senior", 34, 4.0, d,d);
    Student st5("Selam", "Can", "23431", "freshman", 34, 3.0, d,d);

    r.addStudent(st);
    r.addStudent(st2);
    r.addStudent(st3);
    r.addStudent(st4);
```

etc. etc.

Comment: This is a good solution for many cirumstances, but you may want/need pointers for later application of polymorphism, and sorting vectors of pointers isnt hard, it just requires you to provide a short, easily written compare function that takes two Student*, and return an answer bases on the content of the pointed to objects.

Comment: @RichardPlunkett Do you think the OP is freeing all that memory he is allocating? When he realises that it's desirable to do that how easy do you think he will find it? The simple way is not to use pointers.

Comment: no I suspect he isnt freeing it. He looks to be creating objects the way a java programmer might, and I expect it will all go to hell. Yes, the simple way it to not use pointers in most/all of the places he is using them. Value semantics and the std::string  class would have made this fair more likely to work first time.